# Can't create an app id for a team account on app store connect

Tags: ios, deployment, app-store, app-id

I'm trying to upload an app on app store using a team account but when I'm trying to create an app id in Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles or Xcode it creates one for my personal account not the team account (I'm an admin in this one)
And also I'm not having this permission (Access to Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles) in this attached image and it seems like this permission is not available to me when the account owner tried to check this

[Check this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ammIA.jpg)